# Lenovo laptop keyboard acts as if key is stuck

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, keyboard, thinkpad

For the past year or so, my Lenovo W530 laptop has intermittently decided that I'm holding down the 'z' key. The key was never physically stuck; indeed, I could double the rate at which it typed z's by holding down the key! I always had to reboot to fix it, but the problem didn't crop up too frequently.

As of this evening, however, it has been constantly malfunctioning. It starts spamming z's within seconds of logging in - there is a bit of a delay before the horde of z begins.

In Windows 7, I can temporarily stop it by switching users, but it begins again before long. The issue also occurs in Ubuntu Trusty and a live-booted copy of Debian, so it's probably not caused by malware or something similar.

The issue does not occur in the BIOS menu.

I've combed through forum posts about stuck keys and whatnot, but I still haven't the foggiest idea about what's going on. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple googling reveals lots of similar posts about Lenovo laptop keyboard issues. I have witnessed such issues firsthand.

Basically, you can try to reseat the keyboard cable, which may have persistent/temporary effect or no effect at all. If your laptop is under warranty, try to have the keyboard replaced.

Comment: The issue finally vanished after I smacked the keys with enough force. Must have been ghosts after all!

Comment: @etherealflux lol... I'm not sure I could do that to my client's computers

Comment: @JasonKrs Assuming your client is bigger than a hot-dog stand, they should be able to get their faulty computers fixed or replaced somehow.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev  awww relax friend. It was just a joke...